# Is there any way to manually generate a signature and description for an item signed with Amazon DynamoDB Encryption Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have a signed database in our application, however one record has a malformed field and needs to be replaced. It is unlikely that a bug like this will occur again, so we are hoping there is a way to manually generate the `amzn-ddb-map-sig` and
`amzn-ddb-map-desc` fields so we can add the item via cli rather than modifying our application code. The items are versioned so we don't need to edit the old item, just add a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise you not to do this via the cli. Your best option is to create a small portion of your application code which does your encrypt/decrypt and read the item, modify it and put it back encrypted the exact same way.

Doing anything else could have adverse effects on your application. As you mentioned, it may be something that will occur again, so it's worth investing some time to get it right.

Comment: Yeah I think this is what we will end up having to do